# Configurable Lazy loading of Spring beans files @Lazy(TRUE/FALSE - This comes from property file/System Props)

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have more than 50 odd classes marked with `@Service` `@Lazy`.With this configuration I can not load those beans eagerly if I need for any of my requirement. Is there any solution like `@Lazy(${user.property.bena.loading.type)}` so that I can chnage the loading style of beans at my will with a toggle boolean switch.

Otherwise I find two solutions:

1 - Replace all `@lazy` with `@Lazy(false)` - This is risky and not a good way for 50 odd files

2 - Create duplicate classes one with `@Lazy(true)` another with `@Lazy(false)` using diffrent spring profiles - This will be code duplicity

Comment: How does accepted answer provide dynamic laziness? i.e. `@Lazy(${user.property.bena.loading.type)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the official [spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Lazy.html):

> If present and set to true, the @Bean or @Component will not be initialized until referenced by another bean or explicitly retrieved from the enclosing BeanFactory.

Can you please elaborate your comment:

> I can not load those beans eagerly if I need for any of my requirement

Because if you need those beans and those are injected into your required classes, those will be available at the time of first reference to those. That's the purpose that `@Lazy` is serving.

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic lazy initialization you can create a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` which check whether a particular bean need to be lazy init or no. Below implementation should be suffice.

Create a marker annotation e.g. `LazyMarker`

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE, METHOD})
public @interface LazyMarker {
}
```

Create `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` which set lazy flag.

```
@Component
public class SamplePostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor, EnvironmentAware {
  private Environment environment;

  @Override
  public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory)
      throws BeansException {
    if (Boolean.valueOf(environment.getProperty("lazy"))) {
      for (String beanDefinitionName : beanFactory.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
        Class<?> beanType = beanFactory.getType(beanDefinitionName);
        LazyMarker lazyValue = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(beanType, LazyMarker.class);
        if (lazyValue != null) {
          beanFactory.getBeanDefinition(beanDefinitionName).setLazyInit(true);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
    this.environment = environment;
  }

}
```